# how can i set ircd-hybrid server password?

Tags: password, irc, ircd-hybrid

I have been struggling with this for days, is there a way to set up a password for an ircd-hybrid server so that no one can connect to it without first entering a password?
I have the server up and running. I can connect to it, and create rooms perfectly. I just need to password protect it.

Answer (score 4):

In the auth block for your users, you need to add in a password and encrypted line:

```
auth {  
        user = "*@*";  
        class = "users";  
        flags = can_idle;  
        password = "mOgcgwU6biduI";  
        encrypted = yes;  
        spoof = "youserver.user";  
};
```

Use `mkpasswd` from your `irc bin` directory to create the password. Doing this will require all users to have to supply the password to connect.